# undefined tooltip in kendoSlider

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

drag tooltip is always shown as undefined. Is it a kendoui bug? Below are my codes:

```
$("#slider").kendoSlider({
        min: 1,
        max: 100,
        smallStep: 1,
        largeStep: 1,
        tickPlacement: "none",
        value: 10
    }).data("kendoSlider");
```

jsFiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/u4FJp/26/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use input tag instead of div and you will get "drag" in the tooltip.

http://jsfiddle.net/vojtiik/Be2pB/1/

```
 <input  id="slider" value="1" style="width: 100%;"></input >
```

Comment: it works, thank you. Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to up-vote.